# How to create table of code listing

Tags: tables, listings, code

How to create table like this one?
[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us the TeX code you have ...

Comment: Hallo Mensch :)
I dont have the tex code. I want to create a table like the one showen in the photo.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016034/using-multirow-and-multicoloum-in-table-in-overleaf and maybe you will get a start for people to help.

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.overleaf.com/6493712346rktmrcpnzyqp

the problem that I am facing is two fold. I dont know how to set the columns width and that lslisting does not work inside tabular

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of linking to your Overleaf project. It would be nice if your question could be used by others in the future as reference. It cannot, however, be used so if you only provide a link that probably becomes broken over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Table with Code]

Hi, the package you want to use is `listings`

I just copied the settings I used, and commented whatever is not needed but you might find it helpful so I left it there.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%frame=tb,
  %language=Matlab,
  %aboveskip=3mm,
  %belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  %keywordstyle=\color{red},
  %commentstyle=\color{gray},
  %stringstyle=\color{open},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
```

Code:

For clarity I created a separate `code.tex` file with the `lstlisting` code I want to display then it was just called via `\input{code}`. For simplicity I used the same code for all cells. I hope it's clear you would only need to create extra files (`code1.tex , code2.tex` ... etc.) with whatever you want to display for each cell.

Table code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.1\textwidth}m{0.4\textwidth}|m{0.1\textwidth}m{0.4\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Planner} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Planner} & \textbf{Description} \\\hline
\textbf{NOAH} & \input{code} & \textbf{Nonlin} & \input{code} \\ \hline
\textbf{SIPE-2} & \input{code} & \textbf{O-Plan2} & \input{code} \\ \hline
\textbf{UMCP} & \input{code} & \textbf{SHOP2} & \input{code} \\ \hline
\textbf{SIADEX} & \input{code} &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
```

The contents of the file `code.tex` :

```
\begin{lstlisting}
(puton
(qlambda
(on <-X <-Y)
(pand
(pgoal (clear Sx) (cleartop $x)
apply (clear))
(pgoal (clear Sy) (cleartop $y)
apply (clear))
(pgoal (put $x on top of $y)
(on SX $y) apply nil)
(pdeny (cleartop $y))))
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Thank you :) you are a true sorcerer my friend